# Grouping the dataset by cluster_id attribute

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to group by my dataframe based on cluster ids and print all instances of occurrences. My dataframe is somewhat like this

```
Chemical Name,cluster_id
XA323, 0
ZC4-D, 2
XA324, 0
YB1050, 1
ZC5-D, 2
YB1052, 1
```

I'd like it grouped by the cluster_id like

```
cluster_id
0    XA323
     XA324
1    YB1050
     YB1052
2    ZC4-D
     ZC5-D
```

NOTE: This is a dummy dataset and my original dataset has around 3000 instances. Where the cluster_id distribution is like 0: 2700+, 1: 200+ and 2: remaining

Thank you.

Comment: `df.groupby("cluster_id").agg(list).explode("Chemical Name")`

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. Since my dataset has 3396 rows is there a way to get this also in some kind of a dictionary format (or list). like 0: {xxxx, yyyyy}, 1: {aaaaa, bbbb}, etc. as I want to see all 3396 values displayed. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help, if so I'll add it as an answer? `df.groupby("cluster_id").agg(list)["Chemical Name"].to_dict()`

Comment: Thank you once again Tom. Yes it was working well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments you can aggregate it by the `cluster_id`, then use `list` as an aggregation function and turn it into a dict -

`df.groupby("cluster_id").agg(list)["Chemical Name"].to_dict()`